# wordpress admin login page field mandatory validation wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress

wp-admin login page blank validation. When an admin does not input anything in the wp-admin login page @ time give the error like a please fill up input field.

Comment: Yes right it's default validation for login details if your fields are blank it gives an error it's correct its default WordPress functionality.

Comment: thanks for the reply but I want validation message when an admin does not insert any value and direct submit wp-admin login form message like please fill up user-name and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paster this code in functions.php file . I hope it will be working fine 
    add_action( 'wp_authenticate', '_catch_empty_user', 1, 2 );

```
function _catch_empty_user( $username, $pwd ) {
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) { 
        $username = $_POST['log'];
        $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
        if (empty($username)  && empty($pwd)) {
        ?>
            <div id="login_error">
            <strong>ERROR</strong>: please fill up user-name and password.<br>
            </div>
        <?php
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: direct display the message "please fill user name and password " on the page. just load the page.

Comment: @KishanPunjani I have edited code above please check now